# confusion with getline and direction assign cin to string

Tags: string, c++11

```
 string input_a;
 string input_b;

 cout << "Input a :" ;
 getline(cin,input_a);

 cout << "Input b :" ;
 cin >> input_b;

 cout << "Input a :" << input_a <<endl
      << "Input b :" << input_b;
 return 0;
```

How do `getline(cin,input_a)` and `cin >> input_b` work internally to accept an input value? What is the difference and when to apply properly?
Confusion, especially on comparing a given string.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt.

Answer (score 0):

The differences on applications between "getline" and "cin>>" is that "getline" will take whole line of string along with spaces whereas "cin>>" command will only take a string without extra spaces.

For example : If we want to scan "**Hello World**" from user using "cin>>" command , we can't get whole string. Only "**Hello**" will be stored. Whereas, "getline" will help us to store whole line of string "**Hello World**".

Answer (score 0):

```
istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim);    
istream& getline (istream& is, string& str);
```

Extracts characters from is into str until the delimitation character, or per default until "\n".

for the case cin, 
there is actually no ">>" operator in global namespace, it is calling the function

`istream& operator>> (istream& is, string& str)`

in `std` namespace by [`Argument-dependent lookup`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) or `Koenig lookup` 
this actually uses whitespaces as delimiters, so it extracts a word instead of whole sentence. That's the difference from getline, which gets the entire line.